# ADF COPY ACTIVITY unable to identify the (") double quotes in between the column value while loading CSV files to snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I'm facing the issue in ADF copy activity while loading the CSV data to the snowflake table,

The issue is while loading the CSV file to the snowflake table using the ADF COPY ACTIVITY, it is treating data of a single column  as a multiple columns data,

for example:   `"My brother often watches different cricket shows on different ""screens"", but on the same different platform"`

This is the value of single column_A but ADF copy activity is reading as a value for two-column instead of one
i.e col_A=`My brother often watches different cricket shows on different ""screens"`

col_B= `but in the same different platform`

But I want this value to be in single-column i,e column_A

column_A="My brother often watches different cricket shows on different ""screens"", but on the same different platform"

[image: my dataset configuration]

Any alternatives I could do for this?

Comment: How does your COPY INTO looks like? Have you used [ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Use-of-ESCAPE-UNENCLOSED-FIELD-option-in-file-format) in your COPY or FILE FORMAT?

Comment: Can you include the FILE FORMAT that is being used for this?  If it contains the FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY value of double-quote ("), then this shouldn't happen.  Also, what is the field delimiter of the file?

Comment: hi @Sergiu  I've added my configuration https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY3KB.png above, can you look into it

Comment: hi @MikeWalton https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY3KB.png this is my configuration

Comment: When this executes on the Snowflake side, it should show either a file format file creation or a copy statement that has a bunch of parameters for file format.  Can you share that?  I'm not familiar with ADF.

Comment: ya @MikeWalton I did it from the snowflake side using the external stages and it works well for me but as per my requirement I need to load that file from ADF side using the copy activity and  got stuck here

Comment: But when it runs from ADF, doesn't it run a statement on Snowflake?  Compare your manual executions on Snowflake to the code that ADF is producing and see what the difference is.  Then, perhaps there is a way to tweak ADF to match that.

Comment: Generally, ADF uses the internal stages to load the data to snowflake but unfortunately, we can't view the SQL query generated by it.

Answer (score 0):

In your source data, the column value contains comma `,` and double quotes `"` which are the same as your dataset properties **column delimiter** and **Quote character**.

- `Column delimiter` is to separate the column based on the given delimiter value.
- If the column value also contains the same delimiter character, the `quote character` is used to identify the complete value as a single column

**Example:**

sample data : `"1,abc",def`

Preview of data in Azure Data Factory dataset:

[image]

In your case you have both column delimiter and quotes character within your column value, so it is not identified as a single column but instead separated into 2 columns based on dataset property values (comma `,` and double-quotes `"`.)

Your sample data :

> "My brother often watches different cricket shows on different **""screens"",** but on the same different platform"

[image]

To fix this you can change the column delimiter in your source file or replace double quotes within column value with something else.

Example:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your comment @NiharikaMoola-MT, I totally agree with the solution you've mentioned above and it is absolutely worthy but my concern is If I did load the same set of data from the azure blob container through the snowflake external stage using COPY INTO command then it loads the data in snowflake exactly with no issue but if I did the same from the ADF COPY ACTIVITY then I'm getting the issue. SO I couldn't figure out why ADF COPY ACTIVITY showing ominous behavior than that of snowflake external
stages

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I set my escape character to also be double quote (") and it solved the problem for me. This assumes you don't also need to use something else as an escape character.